# Требуется подключить геймпад к плате Arduino Nano V3 (ATMega 168)

Tags: c++, arduino, usb, железо

Есть геймпад Aceline CG-1 на USB, который нужно подключить по Serial к Arduino Nano. Как можно отслеживать нажатия кнопок (т. е. как подбирать коды, скорость передачи данных и т. д.)?

Comment: USB и Serial несовместимы между собой, совсем никак. Поэтому вы не сможете подключить USB геймпад к Arduino Nano.